Django: managment command for project
I have a django project with several apps; I have registered custom management commands for several of the apps and that works as intended. However now I would like to add a management command for the entire site which is not related to any specific app - is that possible?
Have tried putting a managment command in site/management/commands but then manage.py did not find my command.

Django finds the command through a method called call_commands.
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_commands():
    commands = {name: "django.core" for name in find_commands(__path__[0])}

    if not settings.configured:
        return commands

    for app_config in reversed(apps.get_app_configs()):
        path = os.path.join(app_config.path, "management")
        commands.update({name: app_config.name for name in find_commands(path)})

    return commands

First, add the commands for django.core, and this is django add the default command for django.
As you can see from this part(path = os.path.join(app_config.path, "management"), the first condition for becoming a command is that there must be a management folder under the app.
def find_commands(management_dir):
    """
    Given a path to a management directory, return a list of all the command
    names that are available.
    """
    command_dir = os.path.join(management_dir, "commands")
    return [
        name
        for _, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.iter_modules([command_dir])
        if not is_pkg and not name.startswith("_")
    ]

And if you check the find_commands method, django get files that exist under the app/management/commands folder through the pkgutil library.
There are three conditions for a simple Django command.

Create a file that contains command logic under yourAppName/management/commands.
AppConfig must exist in the app. (apps.py )

# apps.py
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'YourApp'


Make sure you have an app added to settings.py INSTALLED_APPS.

